# Select table rows when value from other table is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a way to select rows using values from another table?

[image]

I want to select data on table 1 using table2

[image]

Output will be

[image]

[image]

I have 2 instances in selecting values in table1 that's why I'm trying to use case on this one, I'm not just sure if it is correct.

```
select
case when table2.s_num is Null and table2.s_div is Null then
(select * from table1 where table1.item_num = table2.i_num)
from table1, table2
```

Here are my instances:

```
1. if t2.s_num is null and t2.s_div is null then select * from t1 where     t1.item_num = t2.i_num 
2. if t2.s_num is null and t2.s_div is not null then select * from t1 where t1.item_num = t2.i_num and t1.store_div = t2.s_div
```

I'm not that good in sql, any ideas? thanks!

Comment: How do you get zero price in the result table?

Comment: Hi, my mistake, I've uploaded updated table, price should be the same tho. I'll edit my question. thanks for letting me know.

Comment: do you have other samples of table 2 where other columns value is null also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to select rows using values from another table?

You should use a `join`.

First, look at the output of this query:

```
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.i_num = t1.item_num
```

See how the join works? It matches `i_num` to `item_num` and returns only rows where there was a match (that's an `inner join`, the default kind).

You actually have a more complicated join condition for your two "instances", something like this should express it:

```
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.i_num = t1.item_num and (t2.s_div is null or t2.s_div = t1.store_div)
```

You also want to filter to rows where `s_num` is null, so just add a `where`:

```
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.i_num = t1.item_num and (t2.s_div is null or t2.s_div = t1.store_div)
where t2.s_num is null
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use 'case' in the query? because, I also have other instance to select values from table1 that's why I tried using case in my query.

Comment: I don't understand what "I also have other instance to select values from table1" means. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Here are my instances:

1. if t2.s_num is null and t2.s_div is null then select * from t1 where t1.item_num = t2.i_num

2. if t2.s_num is null and t2.s_div is not null then select * from t1 where t1.item_num = t2.i_num and t1.store_div = t2.s_div

im trying to incorporate the use of "case" because i have two instance

Comment: Please edit your question to include this info, it's very hard to read in a comment. Focus on explaining what you want as output, not "how do I use `case`". Maybe `case` helps, maybe it doesn't.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I just tried to ask the basics that I would need to code this so I can learn better. I'll edit my question. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Yes it helps! thanks for that. Just a question, is the use of "case" not really needed when having many instances in selecting rows? I'm just curious because I thought that using case was my only option.

Comment: Well, I didn't use `case`, and it works, right? You could rewrite it to use `case`, maybe. But you can't use it like you had in your question: you can't say `case when xxx then (select * from yyy where zzz)`. It's an *inline* statement. You can say things like `where xxx = (case when yyy then zzz else aaa end)`

Comment: Wow, thanks for that, I'm to add another instance to select another set of data. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

just join is ok

```
select t1.* 
from
table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.item_num = t2.i_num
where t2.s_num is null and t2.s_div is null
```

Answer (score 0):

use table2 LEFT JOIN to table1

```
SELECT store_num = coalesce(t2.s_num, t1.store_num),
       item_num  = t2.i_num,
       store_div = colaesce(t2.s_div, t1.store_div),
       t1.price
FROM   table2 t2
       LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.i_num = t1.item_num
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Change `OR` to `AND` in `WHERE clause` if both `s_num` and `s_div` should be null

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T2
ON T2.I_NUM = T1.ITEM_NUM
WHERE T2.S_NUM IS NULL OR T2.S_DIV IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*  
FROM table1 AS A JOIN table2 AS B ON (B.i_num = A.item_num)
    WHERE A.item_num IN (SELECT i_num FROM table1 WHERE s_num=null AND s_div=null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select
from table1
left join table2
on table2.s_num is null
and (table2.s_div = table1.store_div or table2.s_div is null)
and table1.item_num = table2.i_num
```

As you said, if `table2.s_num` is not null, you will not join `table2`, and if `table2.s_num is null` matches, then will do `table2.s_div = table1.store_div or table1.store_div is null`, if this matches, it means `table1.item_num = table2.i_num` will be computed.